# Java : How to 20x20 2D-Array with a specific amount of elements

Tags: java

I am on Java trying to create a 20x20 Char 2D-Array with a specific amount of elements. For example,
A x 20
B X 10
C is the rest.

Where there will be 20 As randomly placed around the 20x20 grid, 10 Bs randomly placed around the 20x20 grid, and fill all the empty spaces with C.

I am trying to achieve this with Math.random() but can't seem to do so.

```
package quest;
import java.util.*;
public class Quest 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
    char [][] board = new char [20][20];
    int j = 0;
    for(int x = 0; x < 20; x++)
    {
    for(int y = 0; y < 20; y++)
    {
    for(int a = 0; a < 20; a++)
    {    
    int chances = (int)(Math.random()*20)+1;      
    if (chances == 1)
    {    
    board[x][y] = 'A';
    }
    }    
    for(int b = 0; b < 10; b++)
    {    
    int chances = (int)(Math.random()*20)+1;      
    if (chances == 1)
    {    
    board[x][y] = 'B';
    }
    if(board[x][y] == 0 )
    {
    board[x][y] = 'C';
    }     
    }        
    System.out.print(board[x][y]+"  ");
    }
    System.out.println();
    }

}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here I show you how you can add As. For the Bs you do the same. And for the Cs you simply go through your board and insert Cs into the empty cells.

```
 char[][] board = new Char[20][20];
 //Place As
 for (int i = 1; i <= 20; i++) { //20 As
     int randX = (int) (Math.random() * 20); //random number between 0-19
     int randY = (int) (Math.random() * 20);
     while (board[randX][randY] != null) { //find a free cell
         randX = (int) (Math.random() * 20);
         randY = (int) (Math.random() * 20);
      }
      board[randX][randY] = 'A'; //insert A
  }
```

---

Another option is to fill the board with Cs first and then insert the As and Bs if there is a C in the cell. To do that you have to change `board[randX][randY] != null` into `board[randX][randY] != 'C'`

Comment: Thank you, this is very simple and it was the answer I was looking for!

Answer (score 2):

This solution generates a sequence of 400 (= `20 x 20`) unique random numbers, from 0 to 399, covering each slot in your `20 x 20` grid.  It then populates 20 As, 10 Bs, and the rest Cs randomly.

The problem with using `Math.random` is that you run the risk of generating the same random number more than once.  A better approach is to use `Collections.shuffle()` on a sequence of numbers covering each slot in the 2D array.

```
int WIDTH = 20;
int HEIGHT = 20;
char[][] array = new char[WIDTH][HEIGHT]; 

// generate a random sequence of 400 (= 20 x 20) unique numbers
ArrayList<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<Integer>();

for (int i = 0; i < WIDTH*HEIGHT; i++) {
    numbers.add(i);
}
Collections.shuffle(numbers);

// add 20 randomly placed As
for (int i=0; i < 20; ++i) {
    int r = numbers.get(i) / WIDTH;
    int c = numbers.get(i) % HEIGHT;

    array[r][c] = 'A';
}

// add 10 randomly placed Bs
for (int i=20; i < 30; ++i) {
    int r = numbers.get(i) / WIDTH;
    int c = numbers.get(i) % HEIGHT;

    array[r][c] = 'B';
}

// fill the rest with Cs
for (int i=30; i < WIDTH*HEIGHT; ++i) {
    int r = numbers.get(i) / WIDTH;
    int c = numbers.get(i) % HEIGHT;

    array[r][c] = 'C';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply generate a random number and if it is less than 0.5, you assign and `A`, otherwise a `B`. You would then generate another random number to determine the location of the letter. If the location is already taken, you generate another one, and so on.

When you run out of a letter, say, you have already assigned 20 `A`'s, you would simply generate the location randomly and assign `B` to that location.

Once done, you would then simply go over the array and if you find any empty spaces, you assign `C`.

Answer (score 0):

You can think about the 20x20 2D array as a 400 elements 1D array. Using a little bit of math you can get the coordinates where the values should be put. After that, you can generate random numbers for the posisitions where the A and B chars will be placed. You will have to check to make sure you don't overwrite an already set A or B char.

```
    final char[][] matrix = new char[20][20];
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 20; j++) {
            matrix[i][j] = 'c';
        }
    }
    final Random random = new Random();
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        while(true) {
            int position = random.nextInt(400);
            if (matrix[position / 20][position % 20] == 'c') {
                matrix[position / 20][position % 20] = 'a';
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        while(true) {
            int position = random.nextInt(400);
            if (matrix[position / 20][position % 20] == 'c') {
                matrix[position / 20][position % 20] = 'b';
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```